# PHP mail function giving fatal error but mail is still sent

Tags: php, email, fatal-error

I have (what I think) is a simple script to send a short mail:

```
<?php

$to = "test@test.co.uk";

$subject = "Amendment required";
$message = "Employee: " . $_POST['employees'] . "<BR /><BR />Notes: " . $_POST['notes'] . "<BR /><BR />Reported By: " . $_POST['empID'] . ".";
$from = "amendments@test.co.uk";
$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$headers .= "From: $from";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

?>
```

(I've changed the email addresses for privacy reasons)

When this is loaded, after a delay we get the error

"Fatal error: Maximum execution time of 30 seconds exceeded..." - but the mail is sent successfully.

Am i missing something simple here?

Many thanks in advance

leddy

Comment: Does it happen independently of the email address you set in the "to" field? I'm thinking of some sort of anti-spam measures by the receiving party..

Comment: I tried changing the email address and now i'm getting a different error: Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 Relaying not allowed in..

Comment: next question, how is SMTP configured in your PHP.ini, how are you sending those e-mails - from your local SMTP server, from your provider's server? Check `[mail function]` section in your php.ini file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sending a single E-Mail using `mail` should not take 30 seconds. Never. You should talk to the server administrator unless you are sending out mail to hundreds or thousands of recipients, or the E-Mail is dozens of megabytes big. It seems, though, that neither is the case. I would guess that the `sendmail` command PHP is calling internally is taking too long to respond for some reason.

Is this the full script you are executing?

Comment: Look at the original post, below the PHP tag. 'etc' is written there, so there should be something resource incentive in that (apparently, but not) irrelevant piece of code.

Comment: that shouldn't be the reason for the timeout, because according to the OP, the E-Mail is sent out (the timeout would occur before that)

Comment: This might sound a bit strange, but what if the timeout is triggered precisely after the mail is sent in the PHP Core, and not after the function returns? I'm not sure if that's even possible, but anyway.

Comment: The 'etc' is my mistake, don't actually know how it got there :-\
There is no other code, this is the full script, and it is one email, to one address and it has at most 5 lines of text. I will speak to the server guy, but is there something I should mention specifically? Thanks for the responses

Comment: i would suspect DNS taking too long to return or similar mechanism, so PHP has to wait.

Comment: Then the PHP Mail system is just taking time. Use the `set_time_limit` as a workaround, I can't think of a better way right now.

Comment: Before you contact the admin, one more shot in the dark: Can you try removing all additional headers (lines 8,9,10)? Can you try a different recipient E-Mail address? If all that doesn't change anything, just show the admin the script and tell him it's breaking the 30 second PHP timeout, it should be enough for him to act on.

Comment: ok thanks guys, i will try the above and let you know how I get on

Cheers

Comment: I tried removing the headers (didn't change anything), then changing the email address, and now I get the error:

Warning: mail() [function.mail]: SMTP server response: 530 Relaying not allowed in..

and the mail doesn't send - so I changed it all back to what it was and i'm still getting this error - can't speak to admin yet, but is there anything I can do about this? Thanks

Comment: I meant changing the recipient address (to see whether there are any routing issues between your server and the recipient's one). The sender must probably be on your domain for it to work.

Comment: I did change the recipient to an external address - and the sender address is just a made up address (this does work as I have it in another script), but I changed it to an actual user and this doesn't work either, bizarre!

Comment: is there any chance that this problem might caused when 2 or more mails are sent back-to-back.Meaning calls are made to mail() before the sending of a mail has finished.

Answer (score 1):

Try using `set_time_limit(0)` to remove the PHP Execution time limit. It might not work properly if you have safe_mode on, but it should work otherwise.

Comment: This is curing the symptom, but not the cause.

Comment: If he's looping and sending lots of emails, it could happen easily. mail() is SLOW. I've seen it take 4-5 seconds to send 6 emails.